# Limiting permissions using the Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm currently integrating an android app with the new Android Facebook 3 SDK.

I've got it working, but I've noticed that in "My Apps" on facebook it states that the app needs to post on my behalf to my friends. This is not a requirement for this app and I have not specifically requested any extra permissions. I have noticed that a number of other apps in my app centre can only post to "only me".

How do I remove the need for this permission?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [setReadPermissions()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/LoginButton#setReadPermissions%28List%29) of the `LoginButton` class for this.

this will only set the read permissions.

to set publish permissions you need to use [setPublishPermissions()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/LoginButton#setPublishPermissions%28List%29).

the login button can only be associated with one of these at a time.

Comment: I have used setReadPermissions() and tried to set it to just "email" as a test. This did not effect posting permissions. I could still post to a users friends.

Comment: So if the login button can only be associated with one of these and I'm just using Facebook as authentication (plus email permission) therefore only read permissions.. Then how come it's stating that the app can publish to a users friends?

Comment: you must call the function once and set the permissions you need. Otherwise it will take a default set of permissions

Comment: It still doesn't answer the question. I only require read permissions, yet facebook is setting "publish to friends" permission. As you stated in your answer, I cannot call setReadPermissions() and setPublishPermissions() together either.

Answer (score -1):

If you see that your app has publish permissions in your facebook settings, that means at some point you have authorized the app for publish permissions.

If you want to remove it from your settings, you can either remove the app, or remove just the "Post on your behalf" permission (in your facebook settings).

Then, you can change your app to only request read permissions, and not publish permissions. You cannot remove permissions from the app directly, you can only request more.

Comment: I have not authorised my app for publish permissions (It is doing it without me telling it to, this is the question). Yes, I am aware that you can remove it from facebook as a user to re-test.

Comment: I work at Facebook, and this should not be possible. If you're integrating with an existing app, it may be that you've authorized it in the past with publish permissions. Can you try to remove the app from your facebook settings, and re-authorize with only read permissions, and check if it still has publish permissions? If it does, then there's a issue, and you should file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Also, can you post some code on how you're doing the authorization?

Comment: This is a new app (freshly created yesterday on Facebook). I added the key hash (both signed and debug keys for my android app. These work fine). I then followed the authenticate section of the scrumtious tutorial to the word (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/). This tutorial is very well written so hard to go wrong. I added setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email")) to the LoginButton, but that is it. I tested the app and worked as expected. I went into my app centre to check the app it stated that it had permission to publish to friends.

Comment: Note: I also deleted the app from App Centre a few times to re-test and it still resulted in this behaviour.

Comment: Hmm, I think it's actually the confusing UI on the app settings page. When you see the "Posts on your behalf:" section, it doesn't actually mean the app has publish permissions. If the app actually has publish permissions, there's another section with the title "This app can also:", and it will have "Post on your behalf" with an "x" to the right (so you can remove it). I will bring this confusing UI to the attention of those responsible.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Yes. I flagged this question/answer to stackoverflow and stated it highlighted a possible bug on Facebook side. If you edit the answer with a link to the bug report I can tick it off. Thanks for your help!